# How to add image to v-card in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to achieve the design show in the image below:

[image]

My current design:

[image]

My code is:

```
<v-card v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="mb-2" tile="">
                <v-img :src="book.image" max-width="80"></v-img>
                <v-card-title>{{ book.title }} </v-card-title>
                <v-card-subtitle>{{ book.author }}</v-card-subtitle>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the grid row>cols ...

```
         <v-card class="mb-2" tile="">
                 <v-row align="start">
                    <v-col class="shrink">
                         <v-img src="//placehold.it/80x120" max-width="80" class="ml-3"></v-img>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col>
                         <v-card-title class="pa-0">Title</v-card-title>
                         <v-card-subtitle>Author</v-card-subtitle>
                     </v-col>
                 </v-row>
         </v-card>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/7aOBDcIOke